# How to custom-paint a GridSplitter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm migrating form WinForms to WPF, and I need to custom-draw a gridsplitter, as follows. This is my WinForms implementation:

[image]

In WinForms it's easy to implement. I inherited from the Splitter class and just override the `OnPaint()` method.

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to proceed. I don't know how to use a control template in XAML because I need to re-paint the shapes as the user moves the scroll. Seems that I need to write code behind, but I don't know how to proceed.

How might I proceed? A simple example, such as drawing a line from `(0,0)` to `(gridsplitter.right, gridsplitter.bottom)` would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I created a Canvas-derived class to perform the rendering:

```
public class DiffSplitterCanvas : Canvas
{
    public DiffSplitterCanvas()
    {
        this.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        base.OnRender(dc);
        // draw your stuff here
    }
}
```

And referenced it as a control template from the XAML code:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <GridSplitter.Template>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
            <custom:DiffSplitterCanvas/>
         </ControlTemplate>
    </GridSplitter.Template>
</GridSplitter>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try painting to a `WriteableBitmap` and using that as the background for the splitter.  That might involve overwriting the splitter's template to get things exactly right.  I'm not sure how performant that will be with scrolling though.

WriteableBitmap provides only lowlevel access to pixels, if you want higher level functions like drawing lines and circles you may want to look in to a library like [WriteableBitmapEx](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) that extends the class with GDI like drawing commands.

Code to set a GridSplitter's background:

```
<GridSplitter x:Name="gridSplitterTreeNodes" Width="5" BorderThickness="1,0" 
     Cursor="SizeWE" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.2,0.507" ShowsPreview="True"
     Style="{DynamicResource GridSplitterStyle1}">
  <GridSplitter.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\gripDots.png" TileMode="FlipXY" 
                Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
  </GridSplitter.Background>
</GridSplitter>
```

You would want to set the ImageBrush to your `WritableBitmap`.

Drawing a simpleLine using `WriteableBitmapEx`:

```
writeableBmp.DrawLine(1, 2, 30, 40, Colors.Green);
```

Comment: One of the key-features of WPF is that it allows vector graphics and therefore is scalable. So avoid bitmap-based solutions.